# Add more available jquery-ui themes for users to switch to using cdn

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cdn, jquery-ui-theme

I have a custom theme switcher in my code, which works fine, but when I use a link that isn't a first-party jquery-ui theme in my code, my webpage doesn't look like what the third party group advertises, probably meaning I may be missing something.(The theme I am currently testing is "Arctic" from [wijmo](http://wijmo.com/theming/))

This brings me to my questions:

- What are some links that might work?
- and, How might I change my code to be capable of fixing the fact that some links won't work?

```js
var themes = {
  "Arctic": "http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/arctic/jquery-wijmo.css", //theme from http://wijmo.com/theming/
  "Base": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
  "Black tie": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css",
  "Blitzer": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css",
  "Cupertino": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css",
  "Dark hive": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css",
  "Dot luv": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css",
  "Eggplant": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css",
  "Excite bike": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css",
  "Flick": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css",
  "Hot sneaks": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css",
  "Humanity": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css",
  "Le frog": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css",
  "Mint choc": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css",
  "Overcast": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css",
  "Pepper grinder": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css",
  "Redmond": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css",
  "Smoothness": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",
  "South street": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css",
  "Start": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/start/jquery-ui.css",
  "Sunny": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css",
  "Swanky purse": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css",
  "Trontastic": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css",
  "Ui darkness": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css",
  "Ui lightness": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css",
  "Vader": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css",
}
$(function() {
  $(":button").button();
  $("body").tooltip();
  $(".theme-select").selectmenu({
    change: function() {
      //localStorage.style = $(this).val();
      $("#theme").prop('disabled', true).prop('href', themes[$(this).val()]).prop('disabled', false);
      //$("body").css("font-family",$(":button").css("font-family"));
    },
  });
  /*if (!localStorage.style) {
  localStorage.style="ui-lightness";
 }else{
  $(".theme-select").val(localStorage.style);
  $("#theme").prop('disabled',true).remove();
  $("<link id='theme' href='"+themes[$(".theme-select").val()]+"' rel='stylesheet'>").appendTo("head");
  //$("body").css("font-family",$(":button").css("font-family"));
  //$(".theme-select ui-selectmenu-text").text(localStorage.style);
  $(".theme-select").selectmenu("refresh");
 }*/
  $(".ui-selectmenu-button").click(function() {
    $("body").animate({
      scrollTop: "+=100px",
    }, 1000);
  }); //make webpage scroll to show the opened list
  $("#white,#black").click(function() {
    //localStorage.background = $(this).attr("id");
    $("body,#output").css({
      "background-color": $(this).attr("id"),
      "color": ($(this).attr("id") != "white" ? "white" : "black")
    });
  });
  /*if (!localStorage.background) {
  localStorage.background="white";
 }else{
  $("#"+localStorage.background).attr("checked",true).click().parent()//.controlgroup("refresh");
 }*/
  $(".group").append('<button class="min-tool" title="Minimize or Maximize tooltip"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus"></span></button><button class="x-tool" title="Remove tooltip"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span></button>').controlgroup();
  $(".min-tool").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".min-tool").toggleClass("ui-corner-all", 900) //soften (or harden) edges
      .siblings().not(".min-tool,select") //find all siblings exclding myself or tools with the same class or things that need to stay hidden
      .toggle(900); //and toggle their visibility with an animation
  });
  $(".x-tool").bind("click", function() {
    if (!(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this widget?\n\nWidget purpose: " + $(this).parent().data("purpose")))) return;
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link id="theme" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; z-index:-999;" data-purpose="Lets you select how the webpage should look">
    <div class="group">
      <p>
        Don't like how the site looks? Feel free to change the theme below!
        <br/>
      </p>
      <select class="theme-select" title="Change theme">
        <option>Arctic</option>
        <option>Base</option>
        <option>Black tie</option>
        <option>Blitzer</option>
        <option>Cupertino</option>
        <option>Dark hive</option>
        <option>Dot luv</option>
        <option>Eggplant</option>
        <option>Excite bike</option>
        <option>Flick</option>
        <option>Hot sneaks</option>
        <option>Humanity</option>
        <option>Le frog</option>
        <option>Mint choc</option>
        <option>Overcast</option>
        <option>Pepper grinder</option>
        <option>Redmond</option>
        <option>Smoothness</option>
        <option>South street</option>
        <option>Start</option>
        <option>Sunny</option>
        <option>Swanky purse</option>
        <option>Trontastic</option>
        <option>Ui darkness</option>
        <option selected>Ui lightness</option>
        <option>Vader</option>
      </select>
      <input id="white" type="radio" name="background-color" checked="checked" />
      <label for="white" title="Change background color">White</label>
      <input id="black" type="radio" name="background-color" />
      <label for="black" title="Change background color">Black</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size:0.7em">
      For more information on these themes, go
      <a target="_blank" href="https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/">here</a>.
      <!--may add more or different link in the future-->
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: possibly they use a jQuery UI base default and extend it with each theme meaning 2 files needed

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, I will edit my question to address that idea.

Comment: confirm it first by including ui base and one of their themes